# Need suggestion to fasten Map for a huge Invert Index in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, dictionary, inverted-index

I need to store a huge data in a map for Invert Index, but my data is very huge, and I see that as Map gets bigger and bigger, it becomes slower and slower. We are talking a Map container with a very sparse index, that covers 1 to billions.

In one iteration of my program, some numbers will be calculated, to get many key values (could be thousands) to be stored - **this means the Map will have its size increased by about thousands or so in every iteration.** And I see that in the first few iterations, it take 20 seconds or so, but on 70th iteration or so, it takes 100 seconds or so. I have about 5000 set of data - that is I require 5000 iterations for all these data. With the exponentially increasing time for each iteration, this will take days to compute and that is unacceptable.

So is there anything I can do in this case?

Comment: My first thought is, do you really need to handle such a large dataset so many times. Could you give a short summary of your code containing only the relevant lines and a functional description, then we can think about rewriting it. You may also want to post that on codereview and leave the lower level question here.

Comment: We are testing out some experiments described in a paper, so that's why we need that large data. I am trying this in matlab for the sake of flexibility and productivity, but on the other hand, I just heard from my colleagues that they have tried C++ on this, and it took them just a few hours and so.

Comment: That strengthens my first thought, perhaps you are using the right commands but in an inefficient way. (Opposed to having the right code with one inefficient command as you seem to suspect) It may also be interesting to let it run for a few hours and see whether it really slows down as much as feared.

Comment: We've seen that the speed becomes even worse.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the java HashMap implementation instead.  There is a smkall overhead every time Matlab access java routines, but the Java routines usually provide more flexibility.  For example:

```
%Create
map = java.util.HashMap(5e6);  %Initialize with room for 5 million entries

%Add data
map.put('key1','value1');
map.put(2,20);

%get data
out = map.get('key1'); %Get a value
map.containsKey(2);    %Check for existance of a key
```

This will work.  But ... it's not clear if it will be faster or not.  Only a test will tell.

Also, you will probably get an occasional error when you are developing this way.

```
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

When this happens, you can use `clear java` to purge any Java resident information, or allocate less space to the initial HashMap.

Comment: I am looking for speed increase here. Java will make things worse, I believe.